# MySQL Trigger Error on IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

Here is my SQL, but the MySQL server consistently says that it has an error in the SQL syntax. I have tried many times, but it doesn't work. Please Help!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Score_Count_for_Contestant
AFTER INSERT ON award
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.award = 'gold'AND contestant.CID=new.CID THEN
  UPDATE contestant SET contestant.score= contestant.score+10

IF new.Award='silver' AND contestant.CID=new.CID THEN
   UPDATE contestant SET contestant.score= contestant.score+8

IF new.Award='bronze' AND contestant.CID=new.CID THEN
   UPDATE contestant SET contestant.score= contestant.score+6
 END IF
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Missing `;` delimiters after the end of your `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: Can you post the `award` and `contestant` structures?

Answer (score 1):

I would eliminate the `if` and simplify the logic:

```
UPDATE contestant c
    SET c.score = (case when NEW.award = 'gold' then c.score + 10
                        when NEW.award = 'silver' then c.score + 8
                        when NEW.award = 'bronze' then c.score + 6
                        else c.score
                   end)
    WHERE c.CID = new.CID
```

You can add this condition to the `where` clause `NEW.award IN ('gold', 'silver', 'bronze')` if there are lots of other awards.

Your code doesn't work because you are referencing `contestant.CID` in the `IF`, and it is not defined.  Note:  you could still have an issue with the delimiter, but that is unclear from the code sample.

Comment: Didn't notice the `contestant` reference, removing my original answer then (as fixing the delimiters would not solve the problem). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff! I love you!!! It works! And you make up my mind